# Acivar el BroadcastReceiver despues de determinado tiempo

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi objetivo es que el BroadcastReceiver NO se active al instalar la app, como lo hace, sino que espere a que se presione un botón y luego de presionar dicho botón espere un tiempo X y comiese a hacer sus funciones. En este caso debe de poner en vibración las llamadas que entren de un numero en especifico. Mi lógica: Al apretar un botón (button), se llame el método iniciarProceso(), para que este active el BroadcastReceiver luego de 50s (en este caso). Ya comprobé que entrara al método  onReceive(), escribiendo el en Logcat, y entro. Y como ya dije me pone en vibración las llamadas, eso lo hace, lo que no quiero es que lo haga sin antes haber presionado un botón.

Método iniciarProceso():

```
public void iniciarProceso(){
int i=50;
Intent intent= new Intent(this,Call_Reciver.class);
```

intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ,TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE );
   PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),15635435,intent,0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);

}

Metodo onReceive():

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onRecive","entro al metodo");
    AudioManager am=(AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    String estado=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE );
    if(estado.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        String incomingnumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if (incomingnumber.equals("unNumeroCualquiera")){
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }

    }
 }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=".Activity_llamadas">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".Call_Reciver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">

        </action>

     </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

Este es el codigo de la Activity:

```
public class Activity_llamadas extends Activity {
Button boton;
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
int h=0,m=0;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_llamadas);
    SimpleDateFormat date=  new SimpleDateFormat("mm"); 
    String mhora= date.format(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHoraAct);
    textView3.setText(mhora);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
    textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewhora2);
     boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHora);
     boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             stardNotificacion();
             iniciarProceso();
         }
     });
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getHora);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mostrarHora(textView);
        }
    });
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getHora2);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mostrarHora(textView2);
        }
    });
 }


 public void setTxHora(int h,int m, TextView t){
   t.setText(String.valueOf(h)+": "+String.valueOf(m));
}
private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 int h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();
                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
            }, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
private void stardNotificacion(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("SiyOp");
    mBuilder.setContentText("La aplicion ha comensado a funcionar a las "+getSystemHora());
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
}


public String getSystemHora(){
SimpleDateFormat date=  new SimpleDateFormat("mm"); 
String mhora= date.format(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    return mhora;
}
```

public void iniciarProceso(){
    int i=50;
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,Call_Reciver.class);
   intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ,TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE );
   PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),15635435,intent,0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero use la clase Timer de java para gestionar que el metodo se ejecutara luego de un X tiempo:

```
 public void TactivarBroucast(){
    Date date= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,5000); //en este caso 5s
    date=c.getTime();
    Timer time= new Timer();
    time.schedule(new Temporisador(),date);
}
```

Luego hay que implementar un clase extienda de TimerAsk y allí sobreescribir el metodo run() que es el que se ejecuta luego de un tiempo X.

```
public class Temporisador extends TimerTask {
Thread myTherad;
@Override
 public void run(){
         myTherad= new MyTherad();
         myTherad.start();
   }
}
```

Use un Thread para ejecutar un metodo que es el encargado de activarme el BroadcastReceiver. Para usar el metodo visita [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143107/ejecutar-medodo-de-mainactivity-en-otra-clasehttps://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143107/ejecutar-medodo-de-mainactivity-en-otra-clase) respuesta que dice como usar el metodo.

```
public class MyTherad extends Thread {
 @Override
public void run() {
 Activity_llamadas.getmInstanceActivity().activarFuncion();
}
}
```

Y lo mas importante el método para activar o desactivar el BroadcastReceiver. Visita la documentación [oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html#ToggleReceivers) :

```
 public  void activarFuncion(){
  ComponentName mReciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(mReciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: recuerda en cerrar la pregunta

Comment: como lo puedo hacer????

Comment: ya está cerrada, dando como valida la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

pues agrega un botón al layout, suponiendo que el id es boton1, luego en
tu activity lo declaras, inicializas y le agregas el listener:

```
boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);

boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    iniciarProceso();
               }
            });
```

Los 50 segundos que mencionas ya los tienes en el `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Eso ya lo hice, justo como me dices, EXACTAMENTE ASÍ, solo que el id de mi botón es button. Pero como te comente ESO NO ME FUNCIONA..ALGUNA OTRA IDEA?????

Comment: pon el código de la activity donde tienes el iniciarProceso()

Comment: Agregado el resto de la Activity