# Ejecutar medodo de MainActivity en otra clase

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi objetivo es ejecutar el método activarFuncion() usando un Thread. Al presionar un botón se llama el metodo TactivarBroucast() y este luego de 5s llama el método run() de la clase Temporizador y esta es la encargada de ejecutar el Thread y el Thread se encarga de ejecutar el activarFuncion(). Antes tenia [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141717/error-al-usar-timertask-para-desactivar-un-broadcastreceiver) error(ahí esta la clase Activity_Llamadas COMPLETA) me sugirieron que viera [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it) link. No logre que me quedara como en la primera respuesta me da error al poner el:

```
 @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // dice que el metodo no pertenece a la clase padre
          }
```

Digo esto porque NO SE SI ESTARÁ BIEN ESTO ASÍ:

```
public class MyTherad extends Thread {
 public Handler handler;
private Activity_llamadas activity_llamadas;
@Override
public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            }          

            @Override
            public void flush() {
            }
            @Override
            public void close() throws SecurityException {
            }
        };

        activity_llamadas = new Activity_llamadas();
        activity_llamadas.activarFuncion(); //<----LINEA 47
        Log.d("metodo", "Clase MyTherad");
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Logre que no me saliera el error antes mencionado. No se si se arreglo pero ya no me sale. Ahora me sale este nuevo error:

```
03-03 11:50:57.011 30704-30820/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4724
                                                                             Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 30704
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
                                                                                 at com.example.andry.myapplication.Activity_llamadas.activarFuncion(Activity_llamadas.java:138)
                                                                                 at com.example.andry.myapplication.MyTherad.run(MyTherad.java:47)
```

Metodo activarFuncion() de la clase Activity_Llamadas (Activity única y principal):

```
public  void activarFuncion(){
   ComponentName mReciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);//<--LINEA 138
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(mReciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Clase Temporizador:

```
public class Temporisador extends TimerTask {


Thread myTherad;
@Override
 public void run(){
         myTherad= new MyTherad();
         myTherad.start();
    Log.d("metodo","clase Temporizador");

   }
}
```

REALMENTE AGRADECERÍA MUCHO SU AYUDA...GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione el problema. Cree una instancia de mi Activity

```
 private static Activity_llamadas activity_llamadas;
```

Luego en el método onCreate()

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //.....
    activity_llamadas=this;
}
```

Cree un método que me devuelva una instancia:

```
public static Activity_llamadas getmInstanceActivity(){
    return activity_llamadas;
}
```

y luego llame al método en la otra clase de esta forma:

```
   Activity_llamadas.getmInstanceActivity().activarFuncion();
```

Para mas detalles ver [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315842/how-to-call-a-method-in-mainactivity-from-another-class) link